# SubSonic - calling sproc's w/o parameters?

Tags: subsonic, parameters, stored-procedures

I noticed something with SubSonic 2.x that I'm sure others have run into...

Calling a sproc with results = SPs.SpGetCountryList().GetDataSet(); I kept getting a Null reference exception.

To get around this, I added a dummy parameter in my sproc, and called the same function with an irrelevant number - SPs.SpGetCountryList(1).GetDataSet();.

Sure enough, this worked.

Wondering if I missed something in calling sporc's w/o parameters or if anyone else has noticed this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed this issue in 2.2:
http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/downloads

Comment: Is the original source code available for 2.2?  I have to modify it to work in a medium trust environment.  Also, where is the SQL Server only version - as I don't want the extra MySQL.Data.DLL showing up in my project?


Thanks.